# How to understand magento 2 profiler output?

Tags: magento2, csv, performance, profiler

I've just enabled profiler on my M2 site (csvfile output). But I can't understand its content. Is there any software that could make the output data more understandable?

Comment: you may refer  https://webkul.com/blog/profiler-in-magento-2/